# What is the Java best practice to initialize a class with many optional data members?

Tags: java, initialization

I'm migrating a project from C# to Java.

I have many classes, which have a lot of properties and the user can set any subset of them.

So to initialize the class I provide an empty constructor and the user can initialize any property using the C# initialization list as following:

```
var a = new MyClass() { Prop1 = "something", Prop2 = 8, Prop15 = new Point(2,3) };
```

What is the best practice for such a case in Java?

I've seen the following syntax:

```
    MyClass a = new MyClass(){
            {
                setProp1("Something");
                setProp2(8);
                setProp15(new Point(2,3));
            }
    };
```

However, I understand this is a lot more than a syntactic sugar, it actually creates an anonymous class and places all the methods in the initialization block of the new class.

So I'm not sure that it is the recommended way to initialize such a class.

What is the recommendation for such a case?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create `POJO` for your class and then initialize it field by using it's setter method.

```
class MyClass{

  Prop1 = null;
  Prop2 = null;

// getter and setter method

}
```

Comment: There are other methods, but although verbose I feel this is the cleanest.

Comment: It is always better approach to create `POJO` instead of passing parameters to your class constructor, in case parameter are change in future it will help you.

Comment: The downside of such an approach is that the user needs to write many code lines just to initialize the new instance. If the new instance is only needed as a parameter to some method the user would have to first create the instance, then initialize it, and only then call the method.

Answer (score 2):

Having an object of an anonymous subclass isn't that bad usually. It only becomes a problem when you use constructs like `if (object.getClass() == MyClass.class)` but these shouldn't really be necessary when you write proper object-oriented code. Better use `if (object instanceof MyClass)` which is also true for subclasses of MyClass or even better put any class-specific code into the class itself.

An alternative way to initialize an object with many attributes is to use the [Builder](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) pattern.

Create a public class nested inside `MyClass` which has the purpose to create an instance of MyClass. Because it is nested inside `MyClass` it can access all the private fields of the instance it is initializing. Using such a builder could look like this:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass.Builder().setProp1("Something")
                                 .setProp2(8)
                                 .setProp15(new Point(2,3))
                                 .build();
```

This example uses a builder with a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java): All setters return `this` which allows you to chain method-calls with a simple `.` between them.

Comment: That's a nice approach. Do you see any advantage to creating such a Builder over just changing the return type of all setter methods in MyClass to MyClass and making the class itself a builder? That would remove the need to call .Builder and then .build in the end.

Comment: The explicit build allows one to validate the combination of inputs, and perform class initialization that can only take place once all the inputs are known. Lots of commercial APIs use this pattern, including Google guava, Amazon AWS, and protocol buffers.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use a definition class.

```
public class VehicleDef
{
     int wheels;
     Color color;
     Brand brand;
     Type type;
     int cylinderVolume;
     ....
}
```

Now, you can create a constructor that takes this VehicleDef class as an argument:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    // all props here:

    public Vehicle (VehicleDef def)
    {
        // set properties and do stuff
    }
}
```

Now, you can use it like this:

```
VehicleDef def;
def.wheels = 4;
def.color = Color.RED;
def.brand = Brands.HONDA;
def.type = VehicleTypes.CAR;
def.cylinderVolume = 400;

Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle(def);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without double-brace-initialization:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
a.setProp1("Something");
a.setProp2(8);
a.setProp15(new Point(2,3));
```

This is the way to go if the number of (mutable) properties is large.

When some properties are immutable (final), adding a specific constructor is necessary.
Any number of additional constructors can be added to pass properties at construction time (if possible, also add a default constuctor with no args):

```
public class MyClass {

    // default constructor
    public MyClass() {
    }

    // convenience constructor
    public MyClass(String s, int i, Point p) {
        setProp1(s);
        setProp2(i);
        setProp15(p);
    }
}
```